# Arbitrary properties for test and queries/test runs based on them?

Tags: java, testing, fitnesse, fit-framework

Our testers have the requirement to store multiple properties for a test that are not present in the "properties". They want to store priority, a description(not in the wiki page itself) and so on. they don't want to use the tagging mechanism.

Is there a way to store any kind of new xml node in the properties.xml for a test? these properties should then be used to:

1. query the fields via the search screen
2. run tests based on the "SuiteResponder" ?suite=xxx&TAGx=abc&TAGy=cde
3. they should be returned by "?properties" responder.
4. they should appear in the test history of the test run

In essence they want to store any kind of "meta" information in the properties.xml and work with them in all kinds of ways, search, run etc. Does anybody here know if there is already something available in that direction? If not I think we have to "pimp" these features into fitnesse to make our testers happy.

PS: I've also posted the question in the yahoo fitnesse group

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've seen this on the yahoo group, but there is a story on pivotal tracker for this, and I think it will be added in the the upcoming or following release.

So this is really the answer, that *an answer* is on its way.